# Oracle contains query command parameters issue

Tags: .net, oracle

I got the following query:

```
select * 
  from table1 
 WHERE contains(column1, 'FUZZY(:parameter1, 50,, weight)', 1) > 0
```

Parameter1 is a text parameter.

The issue is the query that gets executed is this:

```
select * 
  from table1 
 WHERE contains(column1, 'FUZZY('value', 50,, weight)', 1) > 0
```

Because it's a text parameter, I guess for some reason it puts the value in quotes. How do i fix this? This is on oracle 11g

Comment: How are you running this query?

Comment: Using .NET:
`code`using(OracleCommand command = OracleCommand(conn))
{
    command.Parameters.Add(":parameter1", txtValue.Text);
}

I made sure the txtValue does not contain quotations. It simply contains the value value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
String param = "FUZZY("+txtValue.Text+", 50,, weight)";
```

And send it as parameter

```
select * from table1 WHERE contains(column1, :param, 1) > 0
```